# libcurl malformed url error after upgrade (CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT)

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I have a C++ client that connects to servers using libcurl on FreeBSD.  The system administrators recently update the FreeBSD image and install ports.  The system went from cURL version 7.24.0_2 to cURL version 7.31.0.  (File name went from libcurl.so.6 to lib curl.so.7 for what that's worth.)

I recompiled my program to link against the new library.

Now I am getting return value 3 (CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT) from my call to curl_easy_perform(3), and the error message string returned is " malformed".

However, nothing else has changed.  The URL is unchanged, and has been verified as correct.

Stranger still, the command line "curl" program works fine; isn't it using the same library?!

I've spent a couple hours reading the release notes for libcurl but couldn't spot anything that suggested a reason as to why this should now fail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You didn't show how the URL looked like nor any source code or anything, it's not really possible for us to tell what's going on. Yes, curl uses the same lib so it would point to a problem in your app rather than in libcurl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the sysadmins built cURL wrong.  A new install and it works.